# Nuxt.js failed to dynamically compile templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a problem with nuxt
When I load index.vue page and click on the nuxt-link to load another page I am getting an error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
> found in
> ---> 
>
> <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue

I use SSR. I think nuxt.js failed to dynamically compile templates
After goggling I found this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only
And i tried add it to config

```
build: {
  extend (config) {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  transpile: [/^element-ui/]
}
```

But then I got an error: "These dependencies were not found"
Maybe anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Some options from nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'server',
  css: [
    'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/element-ui.js',
    { src: '@/plugins/stickySidebar.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    '@Nuxtjs/eslint-module'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@Nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  build: {
    // extend (config) {
    //   config.resolve.alias = {
    //     'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    //   }
    // },
    transpile: [/^element-ui/]
  }
}
```

BTW, I'm using yarn
Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@Nuxtjs/axios": "^5.11.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.13.2",
    "nuxt": "^2.13.0",
    "sticky-sidebar": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@Nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@Nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

**Edit:**
default layout:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

I've changed to:

```
<template>
  <el-container>
    <el-header>
      <el-menu :default-active="activeIndex" :router="true"  mode="horizontal">
        <el-menu-item index="/">Main</el-menu-item>
        <el-menu-item index="/store/1">store</el-menu-item>
      </el-menu>
    </el-header>
    <el-main>
      <Nuxt />
    </el-main>
  </el-container>
</template>
```

But none of them work

**Edit:**

Found a problem. I've used a plugin sticky-sidebar which crashes nuxt.js routes

Comment: Do you have a default layout defined in /layouts?

Comment: @HMilbradt, yep, I changed it. I tried to make a new layout and it didn't work either. Just added edit about layout